# What is the use of minRepeatability parameter of SimpleBlobDetector in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

There is a `minRepeatability` parameter in `SimpleBlobDetector` in OpenCV. What is the use of this parameter. How will it affect blob detection if I vary it from 1 to, say, 20?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The relevant code is in [blobdetector.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/blobdetector.cpp).

The `detect` function (the only one using `minRepeatability`):

1. finds blob centers at different threshold (from `minThreshold` to `maxThreshold` with `thresholdStep`) on the grayscale image
2. if the same blob center is found at different threshold values (within a `minDistBetweenBlobs`), then it (basically) increases a counter for that blob.
3. if the counter for each blob is >= `minRepeatability`, then it's a *stable* blob, and produces a `KeyPoint`, otherwise the blob is discarded.

**So `minRepeatability` is how a blob is *stable* across different thresholds on the grayscale image.**

Default values are:

```
thresholdStep = 10;
minThreshold = 50;
maxThreshold = 220;
minRepeatability = 2;
minDistBetweenBlobs = 10;
```

The max valid value for `minRepeatability` is then: `(maxThreshold - minThreshold) / thresholdStep`, or every blob will be discarded. The minimum valid value is 1, meaning that all blobs will be kept and provide a `KeyPoint`.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is very old, however I do not understand why the same blob centre would not be found across different thresholds other than the obvious case where the blob disappears due to the threshold. Could you explain this further?

Comment: just the obvious case