# opencv SimpleBlobDetector thresholding

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using SimpleBlobDetector to detect some blurry blobs of indistinct color for multiple similar images, with some success.

Blurry blob image:

[image: blurry blob image]

Blurry blob detected image:

[image: blurry blob detected image]

I'm trying to tune minThreshold and maxThreshold per image by setting minThreshold slightly lower than the color of most quantity, and maxThreshold to be 255.

1.It seems that min and max thresholds do not have a range, shouldn't greyscale be 0-255 single channel?

2.The threshold method I'm using isn't the best for some images. Any suggestions on tuning these values? / Alternate method?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32974766/5008845). Yes, the two thresholds are in range 0-255.

Comment: @Miki Thanks for the comment. It's interesting how I'm able to exceed the range 0-255 and still get contours. I'll try raising minRepeatability.

Comment: the maxThreshold will be internally saturated to 255

Comment: It is very hard to tell if you are doing something wrong without seeing your code.